# Determine to which PSSession a command belongs to?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange, azure-activedirectory

Good evening

Some PowerShell Commands are available online and on-premise, for example, `Get-MailContact`

Is there a way to recognize if the local Server or e.g. Exchange online is answering the call of this kind of command?

I would have expected to be able to ask the PSSession what commands it responds to, but that seems to be a red herring.

Thanks a lot for any help!
Kind regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

Use prefixes when using imported cmldets.

> Import-PSSession
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-pssession?view=powershell-7.1
>
> Import-PSSession
> ***[-Prefix ]***
> [-DisableNameChecking]
> [[-CommandName] <String[]>]
> [-AllowClobber]
> [-ArgumentList <Object[]>]
> [-CommandType ]
> [-Module <String[]>]
> [-FullyQualifiedModule <ModuleSpecification[]>]
> [[-FormatTypeName] <String[]>]
> [-Certificate ]
> [-Session] 
> []

You can use any prefix you choose.

Example(s):

```
Import-PSSession -Session $ExchangeOnPremSession -Prefix 'EXP'
Import-PSSession -Session $ExchangeOnlineSession -Prefix 'EXO'
Import-PSSession -Session $SkypeOnlineSession -Prefix 'SOL'
Import-PSSession -Session $SqlSession -Prefix 'SQL'
Import-PSSession -Session $WapSession -Prefix 'WAP'
```

This way, when using Exchange Online your cmdlets would be shows as Get-ExoMail and on-premises would be the normal Get-Mail cmdlet. Or you can explicitly use say EXO for online, and EXP for on-premises.

So, the use case would be:

```
Get-ExoMailbox
```

Or

```
Get-ExpMailbox
```

... all else about the cmdlet is the same.

This prefix thing is not new, you can do this for your custom stuff (variables, functions, etc) as well, for easy discovery, use, and disposal.

***Note:

The new Exchange Online already does this, in the new modules, so, no need for the prefix.***

> Get-EXOMailbox
>
> Module: ExchangePowerShell
>
> Applies to: Exchange Online
>
> This cmdlet is available only in the Exchange Online PowerShell V2
> module. For more information, see About the Exchange Online PowerShell
> V2 module.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-exomailbox?view=exchange-ps

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following command to view which module the command is using:

**`(Get-Command -Name <Cmdlet>).ModuleName`**

1. If it's an Exchange Online command(Basic):

[image]

2. If it's an Exchange Online command(V2):

[image]

3. If it's an on-prem Exchange command, there will a server fqdn output in PowerShell:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
(Get-Command *exch*).source
```

If command is from remote session it would respond similar to this:

```
tmp_rusnwadj.rm5
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).